# Why std::process::Command doesn't work in Windows?

Tags: rust

From this documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html
I try to use this on my Windows machine:

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    use std::process::Command;

    let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
        Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/C", "echo hello"])
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
    } else {
        Command::new("sh")
            .arg("-c")
            .arg("echo hello")
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
    };

    let hello = output.stdout;
}
```

It should print "hello" but `cargo run` prints nothing. I also try `mkdir` or `rm` command. It prints error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'failed to execute process: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }', src\main.rs:9:14
```

so far nothing works.

[image]

Comment: I don't use Windows but... "It should print 'hello'" why? Don't spawned processes run in a subshell? Isn't that why you're capturing stdout in that assignment at the end?

Comment: Could it be possible that the _hello_ windows disappears immediately as it has no `pause` at the end? Have you tried running something like `notepad.exe`?

Comment: Yes... it works now. It turns out that I need to print the hello variable somehow since this `.output()` put the result into a variable. Also `notepad.exe` works. It was so silly of me not trying this sooner. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, I tried on my windows and for print commande I added `println!("{:?}", str::from_utf8(&hello).unwrap());`